# How to Configure AWS X-Ray for node.js app not using Express middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, aws-xray, distributed-tracing, application-monitoring

I am trying to integrate AWS X-Ray with my nodejs api hosted on AWS Lambda(serverless).
X-Ray works as intended for api using express middleware and able to see traces on AWS Console.
For async functions without express framework, I am facing issues while integration.

Tried enabling Manual mode, but facing- *Lambda not supporting manual mode* error.

Referred [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray-sdk-for-nodejs/latest/reference/) - *Developing custom solutions for automatic mode* section but no luck.

Can someone help me out with this?

```
'use strict';
const AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk-core');
const Aws = AWSXRay.captureAWS(require('aws-sdk'))
const capturePostgres = require('aws-xray-sdk-postgres');
const { Client } = capturePostgres(require('pg'));

module.exports.test = async (event, context) => {
         var ns = AWSXRay.getNamespace();
         const segment = newAWSXRay.Segment('Notifications_push');
         ns.enter(ns.createContext());
         AWSXRay.setSegment(segment_push);
         .... };
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this. I have a couple of Fargate services that does not use express.

Answer (score 0):

So, when in Lambda, the SDK creates a placeholder (facade) segment automatically. More in-depth explanation here: https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/issues/148

All you need is:

```
const AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk-core');
//lets patch the AWS SDK
const Aws = AWSXRay.captureAWS(require('aws-sdk'));

module.exports.test = async (event, context) => {
  //All capturing will work out of box

  var sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});
  var params = {...}

  //no need to add code, just regular SQS call
  sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Success", data.MessageId);
    }
  });

  //if you want to create subsegments manually simply do
  const seg = AWSXRay.getSegment();
  const subseg = seg.addSubsegment('mynewsubsegment');
  subseg.close();
  //no need to close the Lambda segment
};
```

Additional documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-tracing.html

Comment: I have a non express nodeja application. when i test your solution, i am getting `undefined` for `AWSXRay.getSegment()`. Can you help me on this?